# When to filter/sanitize data: before database insertion or before display?

Tags: php, html, filter, sanitize

As I prepare to tackle the issue of input data filtering and sanitization, I'm curious whether there's a best (or most used) practice? Is it better to filter/sanitize the data (of HTML, JavaScript, etc.) before inserting the data into the database, or should it be done when the data is being prepared for display in HTML?

A few notes:

- I'm doing this in PHP, but I suspect the answer to this is language agnostic. But if you have any recommendations specific to PHP, please share!
- This is not an issue of escaping the data for database insertion. I already have PDO handling that quite well.

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When it comes to displaying user submitted data, the generally accepted mantra is to "Filter input, escape output."

I would recommend against escaping things like html entities, etc, before going into the database, because you never know when HTML will not be your display medium. Also, different types of situations require different types of output escaping. For example, embedding a string in Javascript requires different escaping than in HTML. Doing this before may lull yourself into a false sense of security.

So, the basic rule of thumb is, sanitize before use and specifically for that use; not pre-emptively.

(Please note, I am not talking about escaping output for SQL, just for display. Please still do escape data bound for an SQL string).

Comment: +1 Excellent tip overall, especially the "I would recommend against escaping things like html entities, etc, before going into the database, because you never know when HTML will not be your display medium"

Answer (score 12):

i like to have/store the data in original form.
i only escape/filter the data depending on the location where i'm using it.

- on a webpage - encode all html
- on sql - kill quotes
- on url - urlencoding
- on printers - encode escape commands
- on what ever - encode it for that job

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two types of filtering/sanitization you should care about :

- SQL
- HTML

Obviously, the first one has to be taken care of before/when inserting the data to the database, to prevent SQL Injections.

But you already know that, as you said, so I won't talk about it more.

The second one, on the other hand, is a more interesting question :

- if your users must be able to edit their data, it is interesting to return it to them the same way they entered it at first ; which means you have to store a "non-html-specialchars-escaped" version.
- if you want to have some HTML displayed, you'll maybe use something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) : very powerful... But might require a bit too much resources if you are running it on every data when it has to be displayed...

So :

- If you want to display some HTML, using a heavy tool to validate/filter it, I'd say you need to store an already filtered/whatever version into the database, to not destroy the server, re-creating it each time the data is displayed

  - but you also need to store the "original" version *(see what I said before)*
  - In that case, I'd probably store both versions into database, even if it takes more place... Or at least use some good caching mecanism, to not-recreate the clean version over and over again.
- If you don't want to display any HTML, you will use `htmlspecialchars` or an equivalent, which is probably not that much of a CPU-eater... So it probably doesn't matter much

  - you still need to store the "original" version
  - but escaping when you are outputing the data might be OK.

BTW, the first solution is also nice if users are using something like bbcode/markdown/wiki when inputting the data, and you are rendering it in HTML...

*At least, as long as it's displayed more often than it's updated -- and especially if you don't use any cache to store the clean HTML version.*

Comment: (Re: sanitizing HTML specifically) 8 years later, now that clientside rendering is so common, the "I'd say you need to store an already filtered/whatever version into the database, to not destroy the server" point here is now even more relevant. Sanitizing HTML is a costly operation, and in many cases it will make more sense to sanitize upon save instead of upon display. There are obvious tradeoffs here in terms of the operation being lossy and a data migration being required to update the sanitization rules, but there are many cases where those tradeoffs are more than worthwhile.

Answer (score 6):

Sanitize it for the database before putting it in the database, if necessary (i.e. if you're not using a database interactivity layer that handles that for you).  Sanitize it for display before display.

Storing things in a presently unnecessary quoted form just causes too many problems.

Answer (score 6):

I always say escape things immediately before passing them to the place they need to be escaped. Your database doesn't care about HTML, so escaping HTML before storing in the database is unnecessary. If you ever want to output as something other than HTML, or change which tags are allowed/disallowed, you might have a bit of work ahead of you. Also, it's easier to remember to do the escaping right when it needs to be done, than at some much earlier stage in the process.

It's also worth noting that HTML-escaped strings can be much longer than the original input. If I put a Japanese username in a registration form, the original string might only be 4 Unicode characters, but HTML escaping may convert it to a long string of "&#12345;&#67890;&#18504;&#31337;". Then my 4-character username is too long for your database field, and gets stored as two Japanese characters plus half an escape code, which also probably prevents me from logging in.

Beware that browsers tend to escape some things like non-English text in submitted forms themselves, and there will always be that smartass who uses a Japanese username everywhere. So you may want to actually *unescape* HTML before storing.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly it depends on what you are planning to do with the input, as well as your development environment.

In most cases you want original input. This way you get the power to tweak your output to your heart's content without fear of losing the original. This also allows you to troubleshoot issues such as broken output. You can always see how your filters are buggy or customer's input is erroneous.

On the other hand some short semantic data could be filtered immediately. 1) You don't want messy phone numbers in database, so for such things it could be good to sanitize. 2) You don't want some other programmer to accidentally output data without escaping, and you work in multiprogrammer environment. However, for most cases raw data is better IMO.