# mysql document upload linking

Tags: php, mysql, upload, download

I have an upload form

documents are uploaded to an (Uploads/Reference/) folder and a link to document is stored in mysql database like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO uploaddate (upload_id, file_link)
            VALUES
            ('$upload_id', '$target')";
```

the link stored in 'file_link' column of 'uploaddata' table is like this:

(Uploads/Reference/6206webhost change.txt)

Now when i run a select statement to this table, instead of just displaying plain text extension i would like to get a clickable link which can be used to download the uploaded document from it's location.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this: when you *render* page using PHP, create a link `<a href="/download.php?id=doc_id">Download</a>`.
Then in a new page called *download.php* get document id, read filename from db using that doc_id and send that file out so user can download it...

**EDITED:**

- with `$_GET['id']` you get doc_id: be careful, check if value really exists and [sanitize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314518/sanitizing-users-data-in-get-by-php)
- Query your db; e.g. `SELECT file_link FROM uploaddate WHERE upload_id = doc_id;`
- Take a look to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user)

I write the example from other post, but check that to get alla informations:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @ABI: hey man, I can't write all the code for you!! Anyway, take a look to my edited post...