# Should I also sanitize data coming from $_GET if i use those without changing the state of the DB?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Should i also sanitize data coming from $_GET if those data are not going to change the state of database.

example of changing the state of database is INSERT, DELETE
example of not changing the state is SELECT.

the problem i think about not sanitizing is this

inside code

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name LIKE '%$word%'"; 
mysqli_query($query);
```

then the data you search is

```
testword%';DROP TABLE tbl_example; --
```

so final value of $query is

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name LIKE '%testword%';DROP TABLE tbl_example; -- %'
```

BUT i guess this wont work cause mysqli_query and mysql_query() can only execute single SQL statement.

Also if you sanitize $_GET then inside the database there is ' then you search ' will your search match the one in the DB?

Can you also show me examples of sql injection?

Comment: See also [this canonical reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for more information on SQL injection, including examples.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your table has 1 million rows and you dont sanitize $_GET as in example above then someone can exploit your search so that it returns all 1 million rows, and then your server will try to display all of those and it will go down. Thats just one example.

**Example**

```
$_GET["word"]="test%' or name LIKE '";
$word = $_GET['word'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name LIKE '%$word%'";
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name LIKE '%test%' or name LIKE '%'
```

Comment: so what if my site is just simple??

Comment: An exploit is an exploit, a bad practice is a bad practice imo. Doesnt matter if your site is simple or huge. As Murphy said "if something can go wrong, it will go wrong"

Comment: if you sanitize $_GET then inside the database there is ' then you search ' will your search match the one in the DB?

Comment: didnt really get that question, can you explain a little more?

Comment: ok if inside you database(whatever field) there is a value ' then you search ' of course you escape so it will become \' will that match the one in database which is only '

Answer (score 1):

what you need to use is **prepared queries** instead of sanitize data coming from $_GET

you are using mysqli like mysql and even not escaping GET ... you need to use prepared queries

you need to use like

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

[from php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

**good read**

[Sanitizing user's data in GET by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314518/sanitizing-users-data-in-get-by-php)

Comment: I think you didnt answer my question, you just suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to find excuses to not sanitize data.  It's sort of like saying "I don't need to put on my seat belt if I'm only driving a half mile, do I?"  Why so hesitant from consistently using best practices?

Moreover, don't bother santizing your data.  Instead, use parametrized queries like the other answers tell you to.

Others have given you examples that even a SELECT is susceptible to malicious input, but you seem to be wanting to even get around those reasons.  Don't fight it.  Get into good habits and do it right.

Comment: OK I get it im just curious

Comment: if you sanitize $_GET then inside the database there is ' then you search ' will your search match the one in the DB? can you please clear my mind on this??

Comment: The best way to clear your mind is to use parametrized queries, so that you don't waste your time and brain energy trying to figure out when you absolutely have to sanitize your data.