# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_GET in action attribute

Tags: php, url, urlencode, htmlspecialchars

Is there any security issues when combining $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_GET in action form attribute like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo "<form name='name' action='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".urlencode($id), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' method='post'></form>";
```

?

Is this correct way of using htmlspecialchars and urlencode?

Cheers,

Nikola

Comment: you can post the $id in a hidden field.

<input type="hidden" name="some_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sanitizing user's data in GET by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314518/sanitizing-users-data-in-get-by-php)